# parent child relationship implementation

Tags: java, jpa, database-design

I'm trying to implement the following 
[image]

1 appointment can have 0 to many subAppointments

a subAppointment has 1 parent Appointment

here is what I've tried:

```
private Appointment parentAppointment;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
private List<Appointment> childrenAppointments;
```

i've also tried some JoinColumn annotations, but it didn't work.

---

Edit:

I've tried Pace's solution ->

```
@ManyToOne
private Appointment parentAppointment;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parentAppointment")
private List<Appointment> childrenAppointments;
```

now I've got this error:
`ERROR: column "appointment_id" appears twice in primary key constraint`

it(Play! Framework) tries to create a table with this script:

```
create table appointment_appointment (
appointment_id                 integer not null,
appointment_id                 integer not null,
constraint pk_appointment_appointment primary key (appointment_id, appointment_id))
;
```

---

Edit2:

Fixed by:

```
    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_appointment")
private Appointment parentAppointment;

@OneToMany( mappedBy="parentAppointment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Appointment> childrenAppointments;
```

and

```
    public void setParentAppointment(Appointment ap){
    this.parentAppointment = ap;
}
public void addChildAppointment(Appointment ap){
    this.childrenAppointments.add(ap);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details about what didn't work there isn't much I can do to help.  The proper annotations, were I to do this and this with a standard relationship would be:

```
@ManyToOne
private Appointment parentAppointment;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parentAppointment")
private List<Appointment> childrenAppointments;
```

Since the sub appointments only have 1 parent this would be a one-to-many and not a many-to-many.  In the database the above setup would create a single column on the appointment table for the parent appointment.  This column could be null for appointments that have no parent.